# ¿Como validar un valor que esté dentro de una lista en python?

Tags: python, lista, tkinter

El usuario ingres un número en una interfaz, lo que tengo que hacer, es que el verifique que el número ingresado sea el mismo de la lista en python, acá mi código:

el "hora_input_area" es el label donde guardo lo que digita el usuario y la lista es
horario = [8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5]

```
if hora_input_area in horario:
        print(messagebox.showinfo ("", "Cita agendada"))
        
else:
        print(messagebox.showinfo ("", "Debe ingresar una hora valida, cita no agendada"))
```

Comment: `if hora_input_area in horario:` y no necesitas el `for`

Comment: por que no usas if? if hora_input_area in horario: y te olvidas de todo el costo computacional

Comment: tampoco me funcionó así, pero igual me parece mejor manera, voy a ver si alguien tiene una solución

Comment: ¿Que no te funciona?¿Te da algún mensaje de error?¿Has probado a convertir el número que recibes en el input a tipo `int`? `int(hora_input_area)`

Comment: Gente, creo que el OP está haciendo una interfaz grafica en Tkinter (aunque no lo dijo). Eso por que usa las palabras "interfaz" y "label", además de usar un tal messagebox (submodulo de tkinter). Para el OP: Si este es el caso, primero te recomiendo aclarar en las etiquetas que se trata de Tkinter, para que no ocurran este tipo de confusiones. Segundo, para acceder al contenido de un label en tkinter, podés hacer label["text"]. Eso devuelve una cadena, por lo que hará falta convertirlo en entero y recién ahí es cuando aplicas lo del in.